# Help me understand conditional probability: why isn't $P(B)=1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have trouble understanding the whole premise of conditional probability, e.g. "given that event B happens, the probability of A is"..

Surely since we assume B happened, we have $P(B)=1$ and hence simply $P(A|B) = P(A)$?

Comment: Here is an example.  Suppose you roll a six sided die.  Let $B$ be the event that the result of the die is even.  Let $A$ be the event that the result of the die is a $2$.  The question can be "*Given that event $B$ has happened, the probability of $A$ is...*" I.e. given that we rolled an even number, what is the probability of the number specifically being a two.  You have in my example $Pr(A)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{1}{3}$.  It is not that $Pr(B)=1$... it is that we look only at the restricted sample space where $B$ occurs.

Comment: A couple of reactions: (1) $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ if and only if events $A$ and $B$ are independent, and (2) assuming that $B$ occurs does not imply that $P(B)=1$.

Comment: Restriced sample space...ok, that makes sense now @JMoravitz

Answer (score 1):

"$B$ happens" and "the probability of $B$" are two different notions. On the other hand $P(B)=1$ means $B$ happens *surely*. When one says "$B$ happens", one does *not* mean $P(B)=1$.

To repeat the [Komolgrov definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) of conditional probability in Wikipedia:

---

Given two events $A$ and $B$ from the sigma-field of a probability space with $P(B) > 0$, the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$ is defined as the quotient of the probability of the joint of events $A$ and $B$, and the probability of $B$:
$$P(A|B)={\frac {P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}}$$
This may be visualized as **restricting the sample space to** $B$. The logic behind this equation is that if the outcomes are restricted to $B$, this set serves as the new sample space.

Note that this is a definition but not a theoretical result. We just denote the quantity $P(A\cap B)/P(B)$ as $P(A|B)$ and call it the conditional probability of $A$ given $B$.